# Bigtiff tile extraction in c# with TiffLibrary

Tags: c#, asp.net, tiff

I have the problem to create jpg (or png) tiles from BigTiff files (70000x80000). For normal tiff I used LibTiff and it worked, but, for BigTiff I think that the only possibility is using TiffLibrary. Following  their examples, I did the following code, but I am not able to "finalize" it, creating a bitmap and saving it. In fact the decoder seems to work, but I cannot get a bitmap (or image) from the decoded pixels, to save them.

```
    using TiffLibrary;
    using TiffLibrary.PixelFormats;
    public void MakeTile(int px, int py, int lxx, int lyy)
    {
        string Origin = @"HugeTiff.tif";

        TiffFileReader tiff = TiffFileReader.Open(Origin);

        TiffImageFileDirectory ifd = tiff.ReadImageFileDirectory();

        // Create the decoder for the specified IFD.
        TiffImageDecoder decoder = tiff.CreateImageDecoder(ifd);

        // Buffer for a sub-region.
        TiffRgba32[] pixels = new TiffRgba32[lxx * lyy];
        TiffMemoryPixelBuffer<TiffRgba32> pixelBuffer = new TiffMemoryPixelBuffer<TiffRgba32>(pixels, lxx, lyy, writable: true);

        // Read a sub-region starting from (px, py).
        decoder.Decode(new TiffPoint(px, py), pixelBuffer);

        // here I am not able to create a Bitmap to save the PixelBuffer
        // returned by the decoder..
    }
```

Comment: Can you view the file manually with a viewer?  We need to find out if the machine is capable of viewing the file.  The graphic driver may need updating.

Comment: Yes, but actually some programs don't show it. I use IrfanView64 and I see it. My actual problem is to convert the pixelBuffer to a jpg or png image and save it.

Comment: I read through the library and didn't find any known reason for the issue.  What is failing?  You may want to read the implementation at following : https://github.com/yigolden/TiffLibrary/blob/main/tools/TiffJpegExtractor/README.md

Comment: Hi. My request is written in the code and in my previous comment. I don't say that something is failing. Thanks.

Comment: In other words: I get a PixelBuffer and I need to write it on a file, in JPG or PNG format.

Comment: My idea was to create an Image with :    var ms = new MemoryStream(pixels); System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromStream(ms,false); and then save with:  image.Save("c:\\image.jpg"); but doesn't work.

Comment: What does work?  Do you get an error?  Which line?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I found a solution to my problem, so I post it. My solution is maybe rather ugly, but it works, so I hope somebody improves it.

```
public void MakeTile(int px, int py, int lxx, int lyy)
    {
        string Origin = @"HugeTif.tif";

        TiffFileReader tiff = TiffFileReader.Open(Origin);

        TiffImageFileDirectory ifd = tiff.ReadImageFileDirectory();

        // Create the decoder for the specified IFD.
        TiffImageDecoder decoder = tiff.CreateImageDecoder(ifd);

        // Buffer for a sub-region.
        TiffRgba32[] pixels = new TiffRgba32[lxx * lyy];
        TiffMemoryPixelBuffer<TiffRgba32> pixelBuffer = new TiffMemoryPixelBuffer<TiffRgba32>(pixels, lxx, lyy, writable: true);

        // Read a sub-region starting from (px, py).
        decoder.Decode(new TiffPoint(px, py), pixelBuffer);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[pixels.Length * 3];

        for (int i = 0, j; i < pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            TiffRgba32 p = pixels.ElementAt(i);
            j = i * 3;
            bytes[j] = p.B;
            bytes[j + 1] = p.R;
            bytes[j + 2] = p.G;
        }

        var output = new Bitmap(lxx, lyy, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, lxx, lyy);
        var bmpData = output.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, output.PixelFormat);
        var ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, bytes.Length);
        output.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        System.Drawing.Image image = output;

        image.Save("imageTile.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: If you need to improve performance, and you have the option of using a professional library, try the [free evaluation of LEADTOOLS imaging SDK](https://leadtools.com/downloads). (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). The SDK allows you to load tiles from any image file, including BigTiff using the method `RasterCodecs.Load(file_or_stream, tile_rectangle)` then save it into any desired file format using the `RasterCodecs.Save()` method.